# Getting past an ORA-00904 error with multiple database query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some code that runs the same query in 2 different databases.

```
SELECT
    P.MYID,
    CASE WHEN 
        SUBSTR(P.MYID, 1, 1) NOT IN ('W') THEN 
            'YOUR_ID_IS_NOT_START_WITH_W'                      
        ELSE
            (SELECT OTHER_ID FROM PERSON WHERE NUMBER = '2554' )
    END AS "ALTERNATE_ID"
FROM
    PERS_INFO P
WHERE
    P.NUMBER = '2554'
```

OTHER_ID in this example is a column that only exists in the 2nd database. Thats completely fine because the query will only execute in the 1st database when the id DOES NOT start with 'W'. In otherwords, this query will only ever run in the 1st database, when the MYID does not start with 'W' and will only ever run in the 2nd database when MYID does start with 'W'.

So the query would work in both databases, however, the query fails with an ORA-00904 in the first database because it says OTHER_ID is not legal in the first database (which is true, but i dont care). how do i force oracle to run the query anyways or work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function in both databases to get the OTHER_ID value. It would just return null in your first database.

For example, in the first database:

```
create or replace function f_get_other_id(for_no in varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
  return null;
end;
```

In the second database:

```
create or replace function f_get_other_id(for_no in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  v_other_id varchar2(100);
begin
  select other_id into v_other_id from person where number = for_no;
  return other_id;
end;
```

Then, your query can be:

```
select p.myid,
       case 
         when substr(p.myid, 1, 1) not in ('W') then 'YOUR_ID_IS_NOT_START_WITH_W' 
         else f_get_other_id('2554') 
       end as "ALTERNATE_ID"
  from pers_info p
 where p.number = '2554'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about the EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm) command or about DBMS_SQL (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm)?

If you are working with scripts on various databases that have different tables definition, this might be the solution for you, though this requires PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem would be with adding this column to the database that it is currently absent from, but adding it seems like a pretty low effort and low risk exercise, and would permanently solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to add another CASE after else checking the database name. Case db_name = db_name1 then your other_id query else some other query lk select 1 from dual... You can get db_name from v$database view.